# Power Automate Flow SQL trigger not working when item is modified

Tags: sql, triggers, power-automate, power-platform

Created an automated flow , used SQL trigger (When an item is modified(V2)) to send an email whenever status of the request change, but flow does not run whenever I modify a row in SQL table.

Answer (score 1):

Solution-

Add a column of datatype **rowversion** in the sql table.
For example
Column name: VerCol
Datatype: rowversion

Again connect the sql and modify data (Request Status) in the row. Flow started working.

See here for details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#known-issues-and-limitations-with-triggers

Comment: This worked for me!